# Converter um datetime em texto não mostra o resultado

Tags: php, datetime, data

Tenho uma data neste formato: `Quarta, 21 Maio, 2014`.

Para guardar esta data na base de dados estou a converte-la para `datetime` da seguinte forma:

```
$f['data'] = $_POST['data'];
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $f['data']); 
$data = $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Depois insiro a variavel `$data` na minha tabela e funciona correctamente. A data é guardada como `datetime` na base de dados.

Mas agora quero mostrar a data, e quero voltar a transformá-la no formato `Quarta, 21 Maio, 2014`.

Então estou a fazer o meu `select` e depois a utilizar novamente o `DateTime::createFormat` para converter a data de `datetime` para o formato de texto que pretendo:

```
$lerNoticia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE");
$lerNoticia->execute();
while ($lerNoticiaResult  = $lerNoticia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $data = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $lerNoticiaResult['data']);
   ..... //tenho aqui mais echos a mostrar o titulo da noticia, etc
   echo '<span class="data">'.$data.'</span>';
}
```

O problema é que data não está a aparecer, o que posso estar a fazer mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que fazer o caminho inverso. Para armazenar, você criou um objeto DateTime, formatou em String em mandou para a base. A base devolverá uma String se o tipo for datetime (acho que é) e você terá que criar novo objeto a partir deste formato:

```
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lerNoticiaResult['data']);
```

e depois formatar a saída em String:

```
$data = $data->format('l, j F, Y');
```

Pessoalmente eu não uso muito essa classe, então a resposta pode não estar muito precisa, mas a lógica é essa.

Answer (score 1):

Tive alguns problemas para salvar datas em **Datetime** no **Doctrine**, resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
    static function strToDatetime($strDate)
        {
            $strDate = str_replace('/', '-', $strDate);
            $datetime = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($strDate)));
            $datetime->format('Y-m-d');

            return $datetime;
        }
```

A função recebe uma data na forma de texto;

Usei o  `str_replace('/', '-', $strDate);` pois minha data vinha com  `-` do formulário ao invez de barras (ex.: `10-05-1996`);

Então a função cria um objeto DateTime com a data em questão e retorna este objeto.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme pela resposta, exprimentei com a tua função e funcionou. Mas estava mesmo a tentar com datetime! Entretanto com a ajuda do user692 já consegui obter sucesso a fazer isto. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço assim:

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($datadobanco) ); ?>
```

No primeiro parametro você deve usar o formato de acordo com essa referencia:
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Valeu

Comment: Obrigado, resultou, mas aceitei a resposta do user6492, porque estava a tentar usar a class DateTime.